# Why is uint8_t using up 4 bytes when assigned to a dereferenced uint32_t pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory-management, dereference

I had a bug in my application when assigning a byte value to dereferenced 4 byte pointer:

```
uint8_t value = 5;
uint8_t myArray [4] = {1,2,3,4};
uint32_t *myPointer = &myArray[0];

*myPointer = value; // myArray is now {5,0,0,0}
//*(uint8_t*)myPointer = value; // works correctly, myArray: {5,2,3,4}
```

In my opinion this is a pretty nasty, hard-to-detect bug and no warning arises during compilation even with all warnings turned on. Why doesn't the compiler take care of this since the size of the `value` is obvious? Also, I though the notion of pointer size correlates to the ability of pointing to higher addresses, not how much memory is actually assigned.

Comment: So `int i = 0x00FFFFFF; i = 'c';` shouldn't assign to the higher-order bytes of `i`? By the way, there's no guarantee that `myArray` is properly aligned for a `uint32_t`.

Comment: You're assigning an 8-bit unsigned to a 32-bit unsigned. the value is promoted to the higher rank and saved. This is a problem because.... ? Try it the *other* direction and your compiler *should* give you a potential-loss-of-data warning. But there is literally nothing to see here. Your notion of a pointer is wrong. The *type* associated with a pointer dictates the storage requirements; it isn't just some address.

Comment: I'm also quite surprised that your compiler didn't shout at you for `uint32_t *myPointer = &myArray[0];`.

Comment: Not sure what compiler you're using, but `error: cannot convert 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'uint32_t* {aka unsigned int*}' in initialization`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why doesn't the compiler take care of this

Because you get what you write!

If you assign a value to a 32bit storage, you will access the 32 bit storage. That is what you write if you say:

```
uint32_t *myPointer
```

If you want a 8 bit value, use a pointer to a 8 bit value!

The compiler takes care of all this! But you can not write a 8 bit value to a pointer to 32 bit value. This results in a cast from the 8 bit value to a 32 bit value!

```
 uint8_t val;
 uint32_t *myPointer;
 *myPointer = val;
```

results in:

```
 *myPointer = ( uint32_t ) val;
```

Answer (score 4):

The compiler warns you at the point you make the mistake:

```
uint32_t *myPointer = &myArray[0];
```

(...)

```
und.c:8:11: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'uint32_t *'
      (aka 'unsigned int *') with an expression of type 'uint8_t *'
      (aka 'unsigned char *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

You chose to reinterpret the value as an integer and this results in undefined behavior. After this you tried to reinterpret a second time, ignoring the fact that you were assigning to an integer. But now you got caught in C weak typing rules: you can cast from uint8_t to uint32_t implicitly without warnings. If you want it, C will do it.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator assigns to the left-hand-side, with the value on the right-hand-side. The previous value of the left-hand-side is ignored. In fact it is not even retrieved from memory.

Example:

```
int a = 0x12345678;
a = 7;
cout << a << "\n";   // outputs 7
```

I don't see how this is a "nasty bug" at all.

If you are talking about class types, then the assignment operator may be overloaded to leave part of the left-hand-side intact (although this would arguably be a poor design). But for primitive types, assignment does not even retrieve the contents of the memory location being assigned to; it just writes new contents.

If the type of the right-hand operand does not match then it is converted to the type of the left. For example:

```
int a = 0x12345678;
double d = 6.5;

a = d;

cout << a << "\n";     // outputs 6
```

I'm not sure what you are suggesting should be output in this case.

In some programing languages there are no implicit conversions and you would have to write `a = (int)d;` .

For better or worse, C and C++ are not amongst those languages; and you can implicitly convert between arithmetic types. Some compilers give a warning about potential narrowing conversions, however none warn about "widening conversions".

Answer (score 0):

It is a result of how values are stored in memory and the implicit conversions happening. With a 99.9% probability, you are using a little endian processor, like Intel or ARM, which means that bytes in a multibyte type (like a 32 bit integer) are stored in reverse order. How a 32 bit int is stored is relevant because the 8 bit `value` is implicitly converted to a 32 bit int when it is assigned to `*myPointer`, a 32 bit integer. When the integer 5 is stored on a little endian processor, it reverses the byte order. So the least significant byte, 5, gets stored in `myArray[0]`, while the more significant bytes, 0, get assigned to `myArray[1]`, `myArray[2]`, and `myArray[3]`.